# Splitting an object key name (separated by a comma) generating a new array of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given the array of objects below - generated from an incoming CSV file parsed by D3. You'll note that key[4], for example, is composed of a string/name of two terms i.e.Community-based (general) & Ecosystem-based (general). I would like to recreate this array of objects splitting key[4] (and the others with multiple terms). As key[4] is composed of Key[3] and Key[6], i would need to increase their value.length both by 1.

I hope that makes sense.

```
(14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {key: "Not applicable", values: Array(122)}
    1: {key: "Other    ", values: Array(8)}
    2: {key: "Green/blue infrastructure", values: Array(1)}
    3: {key: "Community-based (general)", values: Array(3)}
    4: {key: "Community-based (general), Ecosystem-based (general)", values: Array(1)}
    5: {key: "Ecosystem-based adaptation", values: Array(9)}
    6: {key: "Ecosystem-based (general)", values: Array(4)}
    7: {key: "Community-based (general), Ecosystem-based adaptation", values: Array(1)}
    8: {key: "Forest landscape restoration", values: Array(6)}
    9: {key: "Community-based adaptation", values: Array(2)}
    10: {key: "Community-based (general), Not applicable", values: Array(1)}
    11: {key: "Nature-based (general)", values: Array(2)}
    12: {key: "Integrated flood management", values: Array(1)}
    13: {key: "Integrated coastal zone management", values: Array(2)}
```

I have tried the following looping over the above array:

```
dropDownValues.forEach(function(object, index){
var newObject = {}
var keyString = object.key
var value = object.values.length;

if (keyString.indexOf(',') != -1) {
    value = object.values.length;
    var segments = keyString.split(', ');
    segments.forEach(function(segment){
      newObject.key = segment;
      newObject.values = value
    })
}
if (keyString.indexOf(',') == -1) {
  newObject.key = keyString;
  newObject.values = value;
}
}
```

This then produces the following:

```
0: {key: "Not applicable", values: 122}
1: {key: "Other    ", values: 8}
2: {key: "Green/blue infrastructure", values: 1}
3: {key: "Community-based (general)", values: 3}
4: {key: "Ecosystem-based (general)", values: 1}
5: {key: "Ecosystem-based adaptation", values: 9}
6: {key: "Ecosystem-based (general)", values: 4}
7: {key: "Ecosystem-based adaptation", values: 1}
8: {key: "Forest landscape restoration", values: 6}
9: {key: "Community-based adaptation", values: 2}
10: {key: "Not applicable", values: 1}
11: {key: "Nature-based (general)", values: 2}
12: {key: "Integrated flood management", values: 1}
13: {key: "Integrated coastal zone management", values: 2}
```

However I need to increase the values to incorporate the split key names.

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. Is the above the intended data structure you are using? **We need more info**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You actually need to perform following steps**

1. Loop through this array
2. If key is composite then split on `,` and
3. Populate a new array with the 1 or multiple elements from step two
4. While populating check previous element and if there is one then add the length of the values array with the new entry values length and update it back

**Code**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var objArr = []; // Your array with objects as given in your question

        objArr.push({key: "Not applicable", values: Array(122)});
        objArr.push({key: "Other    ", values: Array(8)});
        objArr.push({key: "Green/blue infrastructure", values: Array(1)});
        objArr.push({key: "Community-based (general)", values: Array(3)});
        objArr.push({key: "Community-based (general), Ecosystem-based 
          (general)", values: Array(1)});
        objArr.push({key: "Ecosystem-based adaptation", values: Array(9)});
        objArr.push({key: "Ecosystem-based (general)", values: Array(4)});
        objArr.push({key: "Community-based (general), Ecosystem-based 
          adaptation", values: Array(1)});
        objArr.push({key: "Forest landscape restoration", values: Array(6)});
        objArr.push({key: "Community-based adaptation", values: Array(2)});
        objArr.push({key: "Community-based (general), Not applicable", 
          values: Array(1)});
        objArr.push({key: "Nature-based (general)", values: Array(2)});
        objArr.push({key: "Integrated flood management", values: Array(1)});
        objArr.push({key: "Integrated coastal zone management", values: 
          Array(2)});

    var resArr = [];    

    var finalArr = [];

    objArr.forEach(function(o){
    var key = o.key;
    var val = o.values;
    var keyParts = key.split(",");
    if(keyParts.length == 1){


        //addItemToArray(resArr, key, val.length);
        addItemToArray(resArr, key, val);
    }else{

        keyParts.forEach(function(k){

            var _k = k.trim();
            //addItemToArray(resArr, _k, 1);
            addItemToArray(resArr, _k, val);

        });
    }
    });

    function addItemToArray(resArr, key, values){


    var n = resArr[key];

    if(n){
        //n = +n + +len;
        //n = Array(n.length + len);
        n = n.concat(values);
    }else{
        //n = +len;
        //n = Array(len);
        n = values;
    }

    resArr[key] = n;
    }

    for(var k in resArr){
      //finalArr.push({"key": k, "values": Number(resArr[k])});
      finalArr.push({"key": k.trim(), "values": resArr[k]});
    }

    console.log("original -> ", objArr);
    console.log("result -> ", finalArr);
</script>
```

**Output in console**

[image]

Comment: This looks like it's going to do the trick. Thank you. One more question, and I suspect it's not possible. Could the original arrays inside the object be added instead of just the values.length? i.e. values: Array(122) becomes Array(123) and all that's contained in those arrays?

Comment: Yes that be done easily by adding the array itself rather than the length to the final array.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see how to do that with the code you posted, surely the array needs to be added to resArray?

Comment: @user142553 You can see now its doing what you desired

Comment: Ah I see what you've done. You've just created an array instead. However I needed the values inside Array(122) to be carried through, as they contain IDs I need. Thus Array(123) contains an array of ids of the merged arrays (if that makes sense) i.e the contents of 'val'

Comment: Ok this requirement was not that much clear from the question. That is also very much possible you can just merge the two arrays. Like array1.concat(array2) and pass the array instead of length as the third param to the method.

Comment: @user142553 Please have a look at the updates. I have now done the array concatenations.

Not sure why someone downvote this. :) Might be angry about something but did not tell.

Please do upvote and accept the answer if its helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert each object into an array of objects. Do this based on the key [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
2. Flatten your array using [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
3. Group your array under one object using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
4. Convert the object back into your expected array using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Here's what it looks like

```js
const itemToArray = x => x.key.split(',').map(k => k.trim()).map(key => ({
  key,
  values: [...x.values]
}));

const toObj = arr => arr.map(itemToArray).flat().reduce((a, c) => {
  if (!a[c.key]) { a[c.key] = []; }
  a[c.key].push(...c.values);

  return a;
}, {});

const groupArray = arr => Object.entries(toObj(arr)).map(([key, values]) => ({
  key,
  values
}));

const arr = [
  { key: "a", values: [1] },
  { key: "b", values: [2] },
  { key: "a, b", values: [3, 4] },
  { key: "c", values: [5] }
];

const grouped = groupArray(arr);

// Grouped array with lengths only
console.log(grouped.map(x => ({...x, values: x.values.length})));

// Grouped array with whole values
console.log(grouped);
```